# pyinstaller add-data file not found

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to make an executable from a very simple python file which reads a json file.

In my folder there are only this two files:

```
test.py
data.json
```

So I run:

```
pyinstaller -F --add-data "data.json;data.json" test.py
```

This creates a dist folder where I can find my `test.exe`. However when I run the exe file it cannot find data.json

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.json'
[18556] Failed to execute script test
```

My file is super simple:

```
import json

# data.json is in the same folder as test.py, so no path is provided
with open("data.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    print(data)
```

Edit:

Ok, it looks that when I compile the exe, I have to execute it from the same folder I compiled it, so I have to do:

```
./dist/test.exe
```

If I change folder to dist and then I execute the file from there it doesnt work

```
cd dist
test.exe   --> Fails
```

This is clearly not what I want. I should eb able to call the exe from whatever folder I want. data.json was included from the same folder where test.py was, so inside the exe they should also be in the same "folder"

Comment: Are you running the script from the same directory where your data.json file is present?

Comment: I'm running pyinstaller it from the folder where test.py and data.json is. Then to run the exe I first go to the dist subfolder

Comment: Is the json in the same folder where the exe is present?

Comment: No, the json is inside the exe. I have a python file and a json file in the same folder. The python file expects the json to be in the same folder, but when I make an exe I want json to be accessible

Comment: Seeing this issue is becoming dated, please post your solution if you found it. Researching this myself now...

Comment: Hey @SembeiNorimaki I have the same problem now. Have you found a proper solution? My csv-file is in the same folder as my .py script but I get the same error that the file can't be found. A lot of solutions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296833/pyinstaller-onefile-doesnt-find-data-files) are using `sys._MEIPASS` which doesn't get me further. It throws the error `AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute '_MEIPASS'`.

Answer (score 5):

Add this to the top of your run script.

```py
import sys, os

os.chdir(sys._MEIPASS)
```

This should fix the issue. The reason this works is because when you use one file mode; everytime the app is run, a new directory is created in your computers temp folder. All dependencies are then unpacked into this folder. Pyinstaller stores this directory in `sys._MEIPASS`. So you need to change the cwd to access the files if you want to use a relative path.

Comment: This might work, but I get a permission error to access this folder. This exe file should not need special privileges to access system folders

Comment: Try running this from an elevated cmd. See if it fixes the problem, then we can go from there. Right click the cmd and press ```run as administrator```.

Comment: strange, even as admin it gives me a permission error. I'll check deeper into this, thanks

Comment: That is strange, you can try this from the cmd to see if you still get the same error ```cd %TEMP%```.

Comment: I get `cannot find path c:\...\...\...\%TEMP% because it does not exist` error

Comment: What does ```echo %TEMP%``` give you? Are you on windows?

Comment: Ok, I was using Powershell, I'll try the normal cmd, since it looks like %TEMP% is not defined in the powershell. Yes, I'm using windows

Comment: same from cmd. I'll try more tomorrow, thanks for your help

Comment: This is because you're trying to open a file as folder, instead of `"data.json;data.json"`, try `"data.json;."`
The second argument is the folder where the file should be located, not the path of the file.