# Creating a standalone executable with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable

I have been using Pyinstaller to create one executable out a few scripts. However, even though I am able to transform it into a executable, the same folder also contain a lot of required files in order of the program to run. So, here it comes my question: is somehow possible in Python to create a  executable without having to have multiple .dll and encoding modules on the same folder?

Comment: Yes, freezing your entire project including resources is possible. This sounds like a duplicate of [PyInstaller 2.0 bundle file as --onefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946650/pyinstaller-2-0-bundle-file-as-onefile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `--onefile`, as it is used to package everything into a single executable. If you do not specify this option, the libraries, etc. will be distributed as separate files alongside the main executable.

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile app.py
```